# Why am I getting "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an optional value?"

Tags: ios, macos, swiftui, error-handling, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to enable the highlighted property of UILabels when the corresponding image from a randomly generated array is shown. The UILabels are located on a second ViewController.

My code works when the array shows "image 1", the UILabel with "1" enables the highlighted text property when the UILabel is on the same ViewController. It returns an error when the UILabel is on a second ViewController.

```
let checkVC = CheckNumbersController()

if mainImageView.image == #imageLiteral(resourceName: "1") { 
checkVC.check1.isHighlighted = true
        
//'checkVC.check1.isHighlighted = true' is the line of code returning "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value"
}
```

I greatly appreciate any assistance in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please [edit] your question with a [example] showing the code where you get the error.

Comment: Presumably you are using a storyboard. When you create a view controller instance via `CheckNumbersController()` you are not doing so via the storyboard, so all of the IBOutlets will be `nil` and presumably you have declared these as implicitly unwrapped optionals (using !), so your app crashes. Even if you got the view controller from the storyboard, it won't be on screen, so changing the property would do nothing. You should never interact with another view controllers views anyway. It tightly couples those classes.

Comment: Hat is the relationship between the two view controllers? How is the second view controller displayed in relation to the first?